# Slim php - access container from middleware

Tags: php, slim

I am trying to access the `$container` from my middleware, but i am not getting much luck.

In my `index.php` file I have

```
require '../../vendor/autoload.php';
include '../bootstrap.php';

use somename\Middleware\Authentication as Authentication;

$app = new \Slim\App();
$container = $app->getContainer();
$app->add(new Authentication());
```

And then I have a class `Authentication.php` like this

```
namespace somename\Middleware;

class Authentication {
  public function __invoke($request, $response, $next) {
    $this->logger->addInfo('Hi from Authentication middleware');
```

but i get an error

> Undefined property: somename\Middleware\Authentication::$logger in ***

I have also tried adding the following constructor to the class but I also get no joy.

```
 private $container;

 public function __construct($container) {
     $this->container = $container;
 }
```

Could anyone help please?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34839399/how-to-access-the-container-within-middleware-class-in-slim-v3 help?

Comment: Make sure inside your middleware method that you reference the $container properly: `$this->$container['logger']->addInfo(...)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best Practice to Middleware Implementation is Something like this :

Place this code inside your dependency section :

```
$app = new \Slim\App();
$container = $app->getContainer();
/** Container will be passed to your function automatically **/
$container['MyAuthenticator'] = function($c) {
    return new somename\Middleware\Authentication($c);
};
```

then inside your Authentication class  create constructor function like you mentioned : 
    namespace somename\Middleware;

```
class Authentication {
    protected $container;

    public function __invoke($request, $response, $next)
    {
        $this->container->logger->addInfo('Hi from Authentication middleware');
    }

    public function __construct($container) {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    /** Optional : Add __get magic method to easily use container 
        dependencies 
        without using the container name in code 
        so this code : 
        $this->container->logger->addInfo('Hi from Authentication middleware'); 
        will be this :
        $this->logger->addInfo('Hi from Authentication middleware');
    **/

    public function __get($property)
    {
        if ($this->container->{$property}) {
            return $this->container->{$property};
        }
    }
}
```

After inside your index.php add Middleware using name resolution like this:

```
$app->add('MyAuthenticator');
```

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with [Ali Kaviani's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48125390). When adding this PHP [__magic function](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) (`__get`), the code will be a lot more difficult to test.

All the required dependencies should be specified on the constructor.
The benefit is, that you can easily see what dependencies a class has and therefore only need to mock these classes in unit-tests, otherwise you would've to create a container in every test. Also [Keep It Simple Stupid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)

I'll show that on the logger example:

```
class Authentication {
    private $logger;

    public function __construct($logger) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function __invoke($request, $response, $next) {
        $this->logger->addInfo('Hi from Authentication middleware');
    }
}
```

Then add the middleware with the logger parameter to the container:

```
$app = new \Slim\App();
$container = $app->getContainer();
$container['MyAuthenticator'] = function($c) {
    return new somename\Middleware\Authentication($c['logger']);
};
```

Note: the above registration to the container could be done automatically with using [PHP-DI Slim](https://github.com/PHP-DI/Slim-Bridge) (but that should be also slower).